# Assigning a value to a new column based on two conditions

Tags: r

I am looking for a simple way to make an assignment of a new column based on two conditions. For instance, in the example below, if we have a val1 present (eg "1", not "0"), we assign to the new column the number that the month represents (Jan=1, Feb=2, March=3, and so on). Looking for the simplest way to do this in R. Any ideas?

```
Month   val1    new-column
April   0       0
May     0       0
April   1       4
June    1       6
Jan     0       0
Feb     0       0
```

Comment: Is this actually representative of your data? Some of your months have the full month name and some have abbreviated month names?

Comment: Also, why is there a 2 in "new-column" for "Feb"?

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo, I  have updated the table

Comment: This is just an example, I am actually not working with months in my real data, just using months as a simple model

Comment: @user2900006 Do you have any lookup tables that holds the key value pairs of the variable and its value?

Comment: No I don't as the list is fairly small (less than 6 possible values for the "months" example. I shouldn't have used months in this example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a data.frame with the correspondances (with months or anything you want) :

```
equiv<-data.frame(month(c("Jan","Feb","March","April","May","June"),num=1:6,stringsAsFactors=F)
> equiv
  month num
1   Jan   1
2   Feb   2
3 March   3
4 April   4
5   May   5
6  June   6
```

and then do (also using @akrun data) :

```
df$val2<-0
df$val2[which(df$val1==1)]<-equiv$num[match(df$Month[which(df$val1==1)],equiv$month)]

> df
  Month val1 val2
1 April    0    0
2   May    0    0
3 April    1    4
4  June    1    6
5   Jan    0    0
6   Feb    0    0
```

Comment: Since it's not clear what they want to do this might also be a good approach (+1)

Comment: thanks @beginneR ! my solution is less elegant but more general... (can't have everything, right ?...)

Comment: @CathG +1 for the more general approach :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
 df$new_column <- match( substr(df$Month, 1,3), month.abb)*df$val1
 df$new_column
 #[1] 0 0 4 6 0 0
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(Month = c("April", "May", "April", "June", "Jan", 
 "Feb"), val1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Month", 
 "val1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: I am using months as just a an example (not my real data) to model my data. Are there alternatives to the approach with this in mind?

Comment: @user2900006 It depends upon what your real data looks like.

Answer (score 3):

If the months in your example are just placeholders for other data (not dates) you could turn "Month" into a factor and then use `ifelse`:

```
df$Month <- as.factor(df$Month)
df$newCol <- ifelse(df$val1 != 0, as.numeric(df$Month), 0)
> df
  Month val1 newCol
1 April    0      0
2   May    0      0
3 April    1      1
4  June    1      4
5   Jan    0      0
6   Feb    0      0
```

Using data by @akrun.

This way you can make use of the `levels` you can define for factors. So you would need to make sure that your factor levels are defined in the order you need (here, for example, the first level is "April" so the newCol is 1, and June is level 4).

Comment: +1 I would have used the same `factor` approach if the OP had used a different example instead of the `Month`

Comment: You could also use `with(df, as.numeric(Month)*val1)#[1] 0 0 1 4 0 0`

Comment: +1 too, very nice solution. The only problem is if the corresponding numbers are not from 1 to length of elements (no idea if that might be the case anyway...)

Comment: @akrun - for the example, yes, but in the question it's not clear if the values in "val1" can _only_ be 1 or 0 they say "if we have a val1 present (eg "1", not "0")" which I understood as any other value than 0 being present.

Comment: @beginneR Good point.  yes, the OP should have been much more clear in the post.

Comment: @CathG - you're right about that "limitation". The point is that the question doesn't clearly state what is required. For the example that he shows, it would work though.

Comment: @beginneR, you're right about the question and that in this context (which, for what we know, can be the only context for this question) it clearly works very well.

Answer (score 2):

Try data.table version:

```
> library(data.table)
> ddt = data.table(ddf)
> 
> ddt[,new_column:=ifelse(val1==1, match(Month, month.abb),0),]
> ddt
   Month val1 new_column
1:   Apr    0          0
2:   May    0          0
3:   Apr    1          4
4:   Jun    1          6
5:   Jan    0          0
6:   Feb    0          0
```

Month entries have been kept as abbreviation, since main question is how to combine 2 conditions to get a new column.

data:

```
> dput(ddf)
structure(list(Month = structure(c(1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Apr", 
"Feb", "Jan", "Jun", "May"), class = "factor"), val1 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Month", "val1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```